# How to correctly select from two tables (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database **Sales** and **Appliances**:

**Sales**

```
SaleDate   EmployeeID AppID Qty
---------- ---------- ----- -----------
2010-01-01 1412       150   1
2010-01-05 3231       110   1
2010-01-03 2920       110   2
2010-01-13 1412       100   1
2010-01-25 1235       150   2
2010-01-22 1235       100   2
2010-01-12 2920       150   3
2010-01-14 3231       100   1
2010-01-15 1235       300   1
2010-01-03 2920       200   2
2010-01-31 2920       310   1
2010-01-05 1412       420   1
2010-01-15 3231       400   2
```

**Appliances**

```
ID   AppType              StoreID Cost          Price
---- -------------------- ------- ------------- -------------
100  Refrigerator         22      150           250
110  Refrigerator         20      175           300
150  Television           27      225           340
200  Microwave Oven       22      120           180
300  Washer               27      200           325
310  Washer               22      280           400
400  Dryer                20      150           220
420  Dryer                22      240           360
```

**How can I obtain this results table. (That lists the number of sales of refrigerators and for each sale, displays the total sale price as well (total sale price = qty * price).**

```
AppID AppType          Qty         total sale price
----- ---------------- ----------- ----------------
110   Refrigerator     1           300
110   Refrigerator     2           600
100   Refrigerator     1           250
100   Refrigerator     2           500
100   Refrigerator     1           250
```

---

My Attempt:

```
SELECT AppID, AppType, Qty, (Qty * Price) as 'total sale price'
FROM Sales s, Appliances a
WHERE (AppID) IN (SELECT ID FROM Appliances WHERE AppType = 'Refrigerator')
AND (AppType) IN ('Refrigerator')
```

Currently produces

```
AppID AppType              Qty         total sale price
----- -------------------- ----------- ----------------
110   Refrigerator         1           250
110   Refrigerator         1           300
110   Refrigerator         2           500
110   Refrigerator         2           600
100   Refrigerator         1           250
100   Refrigerator         1           300
100   Refrigerator         2           500
100   Refrigerator         2           600
100   Refrigerator         1           250
100   Refrigerator         1           300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `join` on `sales.AppId = appliances.ID`

```
select s.AppId, a.AppType, s.Qty, 
   a.Price * s.Qty as total
from appliances a
join sales s on s.AppId = a.ID
where a.AppType = 'Refrigerator'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `JOIN`:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485063)</kbd>

```
SELECT
    AppID   = p.ID,
    p.AppType,
    s.Qty,
    [Total Sales Price] = s.Qty * p.Price
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Appliances p
    ON p.ID = s.AppID
WHERE p.AppType = 'Refrigerator'
```

Note

- You need to [avoid using the old-style JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.